# Redirect manual process logs to kubernetes pod log

Tags: kubernetes, logging, elk

I have a pod up and running and we have fluentd configurated in the cluster to scrap the pod logs and push it to Elastic via Logstash.

I need to do some testing where I am executing a process (`spark-submit`) manually on this pod and test that the logs are being parsed correctly. Since I am running this manually, they are not being fed to the pod logs and not appearing in Elastic. Is there any workaround do perform this testing?

Comment: The "pod logs" are whatever gets written to `/proc/self/fd/1` and `/proc/self/fd/2` of the **container's** process-id (which is often `1` but not mandatory); if you have used `kubectl exec` to get into the pod, you'll want to redirect the process's output to those file descriptors (I'll use `$c_pid` as substitution for whatever pid it is, you'll need to determine that by yourself, or edit your question to include those details): `spark-submit ...my-awesome-args... >/proc/${c_pid}/fd/1 2>/proc/${c_pid}/fd/2`; you can also use `tee` if you want to follow along, but that's more complex

Comment: @mdaniel - thanks, it worked! Happy to accept, if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pod logs" are whatever gets written to `/proc/self/fd/1` and `/proc/self/fd/2` of the *container's* process-id (which is often `1` but not mandatory); if you have used `kubectl exec` to get into the pod, you'll want to redirect the process's output to those file descriptors (I'll use `$c_pid` as substitution for whatever pid it is):

```bash
spark-submit ..."$@"... >/proc/${c_pid}/fd/1 2>/proc/${c_pid}/fd/2
```

It is also possible to use `tee` if you want to follow along with the output, but that's more complex. The short version is to just smash together stdout and stderr and then tee that into the container's stdout

```bash
spark-submit ..."$@"... 2>&1 | tee /proc/${c_pid}/fd/1
```